# Do I need to level subfloor with a 1/8" step before installing hardwood flooring?

Tags: flooring, hardwood-floor, subfloor

I removed the carpet from the second floor and I noticed that I had termite issues. After replacing the bad plywood subfloor with a new one and I've noticed that it's slightly thicker than the old one. The new one is 3/4" and it's less than 1/4" thicker than the old one, do I need to level it? I'm planning to get hardwood floors nailed down. Also, would the old subfloor, 5/8", be enough for hardwood flooring?

Thank You!

Comment: What's your joist interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3/4" subfloor is more inline with modern practices, but you do need to level the step, if only to prevent an abrupt visual slope and potential noise. I'd feather out some leveling compound about 24".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Wouldn’t the self level compound break with the nail down flooring Instalation? Would a thin plywood over everything work?

Comment: Self-leveling compound isn't appropriate, because you aren't leveling anything. Find a product that claims to do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should replace your 3/4 inch patch with 5/8 so it is level and a 5/8 inch thick subfloor is sufficient for the hardwoods.

Comment: You're suggesting that he tear up the *newly-installed* subfloor with *thinner* plywood?

Comment: Well details were sketchy and I had pictured a small patch of 3/4 inch ply in one spot of the room.  If that were the case, then yes, remove the patched spot and replace it with the same thickness as the rest of the floor.